# Is it possible to Stop Kubeflow on Google Cloud without Deleting it?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubeflow

I am evaluating Kubeflow for my team and I would like to set it up so that we can use it collaboratively. Our resources are limited.
I set up Kubeflow on Google Cloud as described [here](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/gke/deploy/). This worked fine, until I decided that I wanted to stop it work on it later on. However, there is no documentation or option to "stop" a Kubeflow deployment, only to delete it. So i let it run, as I wanted to be able to work on it on the following day, and the next day I had already been charged 10$. So I had to delete it and I will have to repeat everything from the start.

I am used to AWS where stopping implementations is usually an option, while I am fairly new to Google Cloud. I would prefer to use AWS, but I see most advanced Kubeflow documentation assumes Google Cloud.

Is there a way to stop Kubeflow on Google Cloud, or save its state, without deleting it? Or how would you go about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment it is not possible to simply stop the deployment it needs to be deleted. You can delete the deployment but retain the data in storage.
The commands needed are.

## If you want to delete all the resources, including storage:

```
kfctl delete -f ${CONFIG_FILE} --delete_storage
```

## If you want to preserve storage, which contains metadata and information

## from Kubeflow Pipelines:

```
kfctl delete -f ${CONFIG_FILE}
```

You can also delete via the GCP console, by navigating to the Deployment Manager and deleting the resources from there, see the docs here[1](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/gke/deploy/delete-ui/)